# Value of XML element depends on values of other elements in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

As example, let's say that orange GMC trucks are worth $20,000 while white and black GMC trucks are worth $10,000.

Given the following XML:

```
<example>
    <car>
        <make value='GMC'/>
        <model value='Truck'/>
        <configuration>
            <color value="orange"/>
            <bed value="short"/>
            <cab value="regular"/>
        </configuration>
        <price value='10000'/>
    </car>
</example>
```

The XML is telling me that my sales staff is selling an orange GMC short-bed truck with a regular cab for $10,000.  I want to use a schema to prevent my staff from selling the truck for less than $20,000.

Can I create an XSD file to enforce the restriction that the car must be a GMC, a truck, orange, and priced at $20,000.  In other words can I base a restriction on the values of four separate elements?

The example XML would fail to validate because the price is less than $20,000 or because the color is orange instead of white or black.  Depends on how you want to look at it.

**Update**

According to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/

> Unfortunately, XML Schema 1.0 did not provide a way to enforce these
>   rules. To implement such constraints, you would
>
> - Write code at the application level (after XML schema validation)
> - Use stylesheet checking (also a post-validation process)
> - Use a different XML schema language such as RelaxNG or Schematron
>
> With the constant requests for co-occurrence constraint checking
>   support from the XML Schema 1.0 user community, the XML Schema 1.1
>   working group introduced the concept of assertions and type
>   alternatives in XML Schema 1.1 to allow XML schema authors to express
>   such constraints.

OK, so looking at my current environment I'm using lxml which does not support XSD 1.1.  So, I will have to use Schematron or RelaxNG.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but I really don't think this is an appropriate use of XML Schemas. Schemas should be about what's possible, not what is currently done. Just because no-one sells red cars for less than $20K doesn't mean you want to create an IT system that prevents them ever doing so.

Comment: @MichaelKay This was just a simple example to explain that I wanted to validate "co-occurrence constraint checking".  I'm actually using a schema to detect invalid combinations of values in a configuration document.

Comment: I half suspected it was a made up example. It's worth making the point anyway, though, that orthogonality is always a good design aim, and that co-occurrence constraints often represent a failure to achieve orthogonality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Your constraints cannot be expressed in XSD 1.0.

### XSD 1.1

Your constraints can be expressed using assertions in XSD 1.1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" 
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="example">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="car">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="make" type="valAttrType"/>
              <xs:element name="model" type="valAttrType"/>
              <xs:element name="configuration">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="color" type="valAttrType"/>
                    <xs:element name="bed" type="valAttrType"/>
                    <xs:element name="cab" type="valAttrType"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="price" type="valAttrType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="not(    make/@value='GMC' 
                                 and model/@value='Truck' 
                                 and configuration/color/@value='orange')
                              or number(price/@value)=20000"/>
            <xs:assert test="not(    make/@value='GMC' 
                                 and model/@value='Truck' 
                                 and configuration/color/@value='black')
                              or number(price/@value)=10000"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="valAttrType">
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Yup.  Thanks.  I eventually got there.  Since I'm in Python and love the lxml module I will end up using one of the alternate schema validators: schematron or RelaxNG.